# Calculate percentiles for LMS distribution R GAMLSS

Tags: r

Is it possible to use GAMLSS the other way round? That is I have been given the LMS points of a growth charts and I want to calculate the percentiles for it.

The data is currently in the following format:

AGE, L, M, S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need GAMLSS for this:

**I think either you mean something like this**

The reference table rt contains the following colums:

age, l, m, s

and than you have some value at a given age, e.g. 100 cm height at age 4

then you need a function like this one

```
sds <- function(age,value){
        m <- approx(rt$age,rt$m,xout=age,rule=1)$y
        l <- approx(rt$age,rt$l,xout=age,rule=1)$y
        s <- approx(rt$age,rt$s,xout=age,rule=1)$y
        ((value/m)**l-1)/(l*s)
```

}

maybe you should include sex - it depends how you want to use the function

if you should be interested: I have written a package for doing this the easy way for a lot of different references (and it is easy to add some). it is still beta, but provides more convenient methods to work with data frame.

**or maybe you mean this???:**

You have only the table and you want to maybe draw the 90th percentile

Then you need a function like this (l, m, s can also be vectors, so I think it is convenient for you purpose):

`percval <- function(l,m,s,perc){
   (qnorm(perc)*l*s+1)**(1/l) * m
 }`

Then you get the values of the 90th percentile via

```
percval(rt$l,rt$m,rt$s,0.9)
```

Comment: What do you mean by using Double star in formula `((value/m)**l-1)/(l*s)`
Can you please explain ?

Comment: `**` is a 'to the power of' operator in many languages.